# TypeScript interface with multiple inheritance doesn't seem to include all static methods

Tags: typescript, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

TypeScript interfaces support multiple inheritiance `interface Main extends One, Two {}` However the interfaces that extend multiple don't seem to inherit the static methods from both parent interfaces.

I could totally be doing something wrong here, but I'm messing with mixins in TypeScript trying to make the following work, the code all works as expected, however the intellisense in the editor does not. Take the following example:

```
class ParentClass {

    public static parentStaticMethod() {
        return 'parent';
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public static childStaticMethod() {
        return 'child';
    }
}

class SiblingClass {
    public static siblingStaticMethod() {
        return 'sibling';
    }    
}
interface ChildClass extends ParentClass, SiblingClass {}
applyMixins(ChildClass, [SiblingClass]);
```

I expect that `ChildClass.childStaticMethod()` `ChildClass.parentStaticMethod()` and `ChildClass.siblingStaticMethod()` should all be defined, and a runtime they are. However, the typescript compiler gives me `Property 'siblingStaticMethod' does not exist on type 'typeof ChildClass'.(2339)`

I'm assuming I'm missing something when it comes to how typescript's multiple interface inheritance works. Hopefully someone can clear it up for me.

Comment: You're aware that you're using [declaration merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) to modify the `ChildClass` interface definition, right?  Unfortunately there's no way to modify the static side of `ChildClass` like this, see [microsoft/TypeScript#2957](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2957).  Would you be open to renaming `ChildClass` to something else and having `applyMixins()` return a new constructor?  Also, what's your type definition for `applyMixins()`? A [mcve] would be helpful here. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the reply @jcalz. Yes I'm aware I'm using declaration merging, that is my intent. I'd prefer to not change the name of ChildClass if I can help it.

I added a minimal example here [https://github.com/dotDeeka/ts-apply-mixins](https://github.com/dotDeeka/ts-apply-mixins) the applyMixins function isn't complete, but it's there enough to show what I'm trying to achieve, at least I think so.